# How to get portlet init parameters in a JSF Portlet using FacesContext

Tags: jsf, liferay, facescontext

I have got the following code to get a portlet init parameter  "javax.portlet.faces.defaultViewId.view" from FacesContext.

```
 FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
 ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
 PortletContext portletContext = (PortletContext) externalContext.getContext();
 return String defaultView = portletContext.getInitParameter("javax.portlet.faces.defaultViewId.view");
```

portlet.xml file contains the init param:

```
<init-param>
    <name>javax.portlet.faces.defaultViewId.view</name>
    <value>/pages/setup/page.xhtml</value>
</init-param>
```

My portlet is deployed in Liferay and uses Liferay Faces Bridge. When the above code is executed, I always get null value for defaultValue. Please can someone tell what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

In order to avoid a hard-coded dependency on the Portlet API, you can simply use the ExternalContext.getInitParameter(String) method:

```
ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
String defaultView = externalContext.getInitParameter("javax.portlet.faces.defaultViewId.view");
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution to my own problem. To get the portlet init params, I should be using PortletConfig instead of PortletContext. The code snippet below does the job:

```
ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
PortletRequest portletRequest = (PortletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();
PortletConfig config = (PortletConfig) portletRequest.getAttribute(JavaConstants.JAVAX_PORTLET_CONFIG);
String defaultView = config.getInitParameter("javax.portlet.faces.defaultViewId.view");
```

Comment: If anybody else is wondering: `JavaConstants.JAVAX_PORTLET_CONFIG` is `"javax.portlet.config"`.